# URL rewrite and get param is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I have a form that send param to a page.

But I also have URL rewrite

In Htaccess I have

```
#mon chantier
RewriteRule mon-chantier/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=mon-chantier&cp=$1&devis=$2
```

When I send the form the URI is

```
mon-chantier?devis=eree&cp=eeee
```

and the URI I need to have is

```
mon-chantier/eree/eeee.html
```

I've tried with JavaScript to rewrite the URL with the input values, but if somebody disables JavaScript it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# mon-chantier?devis=eree&cp=eeee -> mon-chantier/eree/eeee.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(mon-chantier)\?devis=([^\s&]+)&cp=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3.html? [R=302,L,NE]

#mon chantier
RewriteRule ^mon-chantier/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=mon-chantier&cp=$1&devis=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```